# How to store DNS records (Go authoritative name server)

Tags: go, dns, nameservers, authority

I'm need to deploy an authoritative name server using and I've found [`miekg/dns`](https://github.com/miekg/dns) package to almost fit the bill  but I can't find how to store/persist records (i.e. on disk ). Currently it seems to store everything in a map but I guess it's all gone when the server is shut down. Is there anything I'm missing or an easy way to plugin a persistent storage engine ?

Comment: Are you wanting to store the data in a human readable/editable file or are you okay just serializing them however is convenient? If the latter is true, this answer may be a step in the right direction http://stackoverflow.com/a/19763256/3570747 (I know it doesn't completely answer your question). I'm assuming you also want to know how to trigger file writes when a resource record is updated?

Comment: @vastlysuperiorman the question is more about how miekg/dns package works(i.e how am I supposed to hook a database and keep it in sync with the server) rather than how to serialize data in go.

Answer (score 2):

miekg/dns is a library, not a fully functional DNS-server. It has built in support of RFC 1035 zone files (originally used by bind): zscan.go to parse zone file and zgenerate.go to generate zone string.

If you're looking for a complete DNS-server based on this library check [Users](https://github.com/miekg/dns#Users) section in README or take a look to [discodns](https://github.com/duedil-ltd/discodns) server based on the library that reads zones from etcd.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution, IMO, is [Redis](http://redis.io/clients#go), which has a few libs available.  Even if this isn't your long term solution, it works well for prototyping.  From there you just need to serialize/deserialize your data into/from a `string`/`[]byte` and write a simple caching layer that loads a saved state and pushes changes when they happen.